# How to check that component is multimedia component in Tridion GUI extension?

Tags: cme, gui-extensions

I using next code to check that item is component:

```
$models.getItemType(itemId) == $const.ItemType.COMPONENT
```

It work fine for me, but I need to check that given component is multimedia component, the $models.getItemType(itemId) returns "tcm:16" for component and multimedia component as well. Is there any other way to check this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check if an item is a multimedia component with this code

```
  $models.getItem(itemId).isMultimedia()
```

this will return true or false.